# Use wordpress shortcode in post title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use the following shortcode in the wordpress post title. The shortcode looks like the following:

```
//Use [year] in your posts.
function year_shortcode() {
  $year = date('Y');
  return $year;
}
add_shortcode('year', 'year_shortcode');
```

Any suggestions how to execute this shortcode in the post title?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 4):

You can absolutely use a shortcode in a title. You just need to use the WordPress hooks system to run the shortcode when the title is called. So if you want to have a shortcode `[year]` that spits out the current year, you'll create the shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'year', 'sc_year' );
function sc_year(){
    return date( 'Y' );
}
```

Then, hook into the filter for `the_title()` to run your shortcode:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_shortcode_title' );
function my_shortcode_title( $title ){
    return do_shortcode( $title );
}
```

That takes care of the Post/Page title, but you'll also want to run it for the `single_post_title` hook which is used in `wp_head` on the title tag on your site. That way, the browser will show the proper title as well:

```
add_filter( 'single_post_title', 'my_shortcode_title' );
```

Note: You don't need a separate function here because it's running the exact same code. So your total code would look something like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'year', 'sc_year' );
function sc_year(){
    return date( 'Y' );
}

add_filter( 'single_post_title', 'my_shortcode_title' );
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_shortcode_title' );
function my_shortcode_title( $title ){
    return do_shortcode( $title );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can apply (save in admin post edit screen) a shortcode in the post title with a shortcode. The post_title is sanitize to avoid tag  or shortcode, the post title is used by many function that a shortcode can break.

To make modification on the post_title, you can use the filter `the_title`

```
add_filter('the _title', 'yourfunction');

function yourfunction($title){
     global $post;

     // if you set a custom field on the post where you want to display the year
     if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'display_year', true) == 1){

        $title = $title. ' '. date('Y');

     }

    return $title;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thx for your reply! The thing is, that this would add the year to every title, but I only want to use it sporadically...

Comment: You need to add a custom field (add_meta_boxes or manually) and check for it to display the year.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in 'function.php'. Try this.

```
   <?php 

   function TitleFunction($title)
   {
   global $post;

   $title = $title. ' ' .get_the_date('Y');

   return $title;
   }
   add_filter( 'the_title', 'TitleFunction', 10, 2 );

   ?>
```